# Unit Root Testing

Tags: descriptive-statistics, unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller

I am having some troubles with the unit root test.
The are some concepts that I do not fully understand. Could you please tell me if what I write in the following four passages is correct?
I am new to the concept so please bear with me :-)

> 1) "If we do not consider white noise, when the value of the characteristic equation is equal to 1, meaning that the time series possesses a unit root, the time series is stationary. On the other hand, if the value is different from 1, this means that the time series is non-stationary."
>
> 2) "Simplifying and not considering white noise, we can state, that there are three main forms of non-stationarity for a time series: trend, drifts or both. A time series having a drift, is a time series whose variance changes over time. A time series having a trend is a time series whose average changes over time. A time series having a drift and a trend is a time series whose variance and mean change over time."
>
> 3) "If the coefficient given to any one of the variables in an AR model is different from one, then the time series presents non-stationarity and random walk theory is violated. By contrast, if we have a unit root, then the time series does not possess a trend nor a drift and the random walk hypothesis is valid in the analyzed time period."
>
> 4) "In a Unit Root Test, the null hypothesis is that the time series possesses a unit root. This implies that the time series has neither a trend nor a drift and this further implies that the random walk theory is valid in that time series."